# EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher Class not found : cakephp custom password haser

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am trying to create a custom passwordHaser. I have create files like below.

**EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher.php**

```
App::uses('AbstractPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher
{

    public function hash($password, $method = 'md5', $crop = true, $start = 4, $end = 10)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword = null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**AdminController.php**
(configure component)

```
App::uses('EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher ', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

public $components = [
        'Auth' => [
            'authenticate'   => [
                'Form' => [
                    'userModel' => 'Admin',
                    'fields'    => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ],
                    'passwordHasher' => [
                        'className' => 'EncryptPassword'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction'    => [
                'controller' => '',
                'action'     => 'login'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => '',
                'action'     => 'login'
            ],
            'loginRedirect'  => [
                'controller' => '',
                'action'     => 'dashboard'
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

**Admin.php**
(AdminModel)

```
App::uses('EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher ', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $passwordHasher = new EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I want to use my own password encryption for this I have create this EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher in app/Controller/Component/Auth folder. but this is not works perfect. It give below fatal error.

**Error: Class 'EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher' not found**

I have already search in google for this issue, but i don't find any proper solution. No articles is there who have a proper instruction to use the our custom PasswordHaser.

Please help me in this concern.
Thanks.

Comment: i think, it's here  `'passwordHasher' => [  'className' =>'EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher']`

Comment: No, Still it's not working...

Comment: No, cakephp don't have EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher class. I have create EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher class for the custom password encryption. See in my above example. EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher.php file contains EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher class

Comment: please give the directory where you have added class EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher.php

Comment: In 'app/Controller/Component/Auth' this directory i have added my EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher.php

Comment: In your `App::uses()` calls, there's a whitespace after `EncryptPasswordPasswordHasher`.

Comment: Yes, you are right brother. That's the problem. Just remove the space after the EncryptPasswordPasswordHashe in App::users() and its works perfect. Thanks for the help all of you.